Using FILTER with multiple conditions on Google Sheet
                    3 (D1)
        1   2   3   
Jane    O   a   a
Jack    a   O/I O
John    I   O   O

I have this tables. I want to use the cell value D1 (can be 1, 2, 3) to find the column to look up the value of O or O/I and return all the names.
Like
1    2    3
Jane Jack Jane
     John Jack

=FILTER(A2:A3, (INDEX(B2:D3, , D1) = "O") + (INDEX(B2:D3, , D1) = "O/I"))
I got to this far but Only returns 'Jane'. What should I add in order to get the desire result on Google Sheet?


Can you attach a screenshot showcasing your input and expected output setup? Also the recommended method to share input data is to create a markdown table & not as code snippet. You can use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question.

Oh okay! I didn't know about the tables! I just added the picture to my post

why would D1 value 3 give Jack as output? Your filter formula is looking for CO and CO/CI & Jack has O in Cell_D4.... It would only output Jane bcoz Cell_D3 has CO/CI

Sorry, I forgot to change all. D3 should be O/I as well. I am looking for values of O and O/I. I will change that too. Yeah O was CO and O/I was CO/CI. I changed it before I uploaded here. But the result was just returning Jane only tho,

Your formula logic is working good provided you've given the correct range settings within the formula (https://i.sstatic.net/o2p29tA4.png)

Oh it does.... I had to change it to B5. It was set to B3 and that was why it was only returning Jane! THank you :)

Using Let to do a filter
Try this
=CHOOSECOLS(LET(x, A3:A5, xx, BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(B3:D5,D1), LAMBDA(r, REGEXMATCH(JOIN(",", r),"O"))), FILTER(HSTACK(x,xx), xx=TRUE)),1)


You Sir Babanana the god of Gooleee Sheeet!
